# How I can make the complex filter for examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, bdd, rspec2

I try to do complex filter for examples.
I have this code:

```
require 'rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.filter_run :foo => true
end

describe 'Filtering' do

  tested_text = 'foooobar'

  [:foo, :bar].each do |location|
    [:first, :second].each do |current|
      describe 'aaa ' + location.to_s, location => true do

        before :all, location => true do
          puts location
        end

        describe 'bbbb '+ current.to_s, current => true do

          before :all, current => true do
            puts current
          end

          it 'case 1 ' do
            puts 'case 1 ' + tested_text.to_s
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after :each do
    puts 'refresh doc'
  end
end
```

When I run "rspec, I have some output

```
foo
first
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc
foo
second
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc

2 examples, 0 failures, 2 passed

Finished in 0.006087512 seconds
```

But If I want run only one example and add this line to Rspec.configure

```
config.filter_run :first => true
```

And I want to get

```
foo
first
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc
```

But after when I have some unexpected output

```
foo
first
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc
foo
second
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc
bar
first
case 1 foooobar
refresh doc

3 examples, 0 failures, 3 passed

Finished in 0.011501239 seconds
```

Does enybody know how to make it work properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify two `filter_run` calls, it seems that rspec treats them as **condition_a OR condition_b**.

You can join the two conditions into one:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.filter_run :foo => lambda {|v, m| m[:foo] == true and m[:first] == true}
end

# or (may be easier if you have many conditions to check)
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.filter_run :foo => lambda {|v, m| [:foo, :first].all?{|k| m[k]} }
end
```

Have a look at the documentation of [`filter_run`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration#filter_run_including-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to join the two conditions into one with lambda, but I did it this way: config.filter_run :condition => lambda {|m| m[:foo] == true and m[:first] == true}